# Parsing form-data into a web page

Tags: php, html, iframe

I'm hoping someone can help me with a dynamic redirection, although I'm not sure if I can do this is straight html or not, or whether I need some JS or php. This is for an online wedding RSVP system (my own!). I'm using anrsvp.com and they provide each guest with a unique webpage. ie AnRSVP - Online Wedding RSVP.

Rather than giving each guest a unique webpage, I'd rather give them just (in the case of above) a unique code like rva858. They can then go to the RSVP page on my web site, and in the RSVP form, enter this code and it to (within an iframe in my personal site) load their unique anrsvp webpage.

So on my rsvp.html page, they type 'rva858' into a form, press submit. They are then diverted to say, rsvp2.html which in code looks like this

```
<iframe src="http://rva858.anrsvp.com"
class="foo"
width="70%"
height="750px"
scrolling="no"
frameborder="0"
seamless="seamless">
</iframe>
```

Somehow, I need the site to dynamically take the form information from the previous page, and shove it into the iframe source http://[forminfo].anrsvp.com so it loads their frame.

I suppose I'd also need a redirect page if they stick the wrong info in too...

I hope that makes sense, and that I've put it in the right area. Thanks

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on the first form, set field id to "rsvp" (for example) and send it to your result page.

Then on result page have this:

```
<iframe src="http://<?php echo $_POST['rsvp']; ?>.anrsvp.com"
class="foo"
width="70%"
height="750px"
scrolling="no"
frameborder="0"
seamless="seamless">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. Would the be using GET or POST on the form? I'm a little unsure re: the coding on that page too.

Comment: if you POST it keeps it out of the url. Doesnt matter a huge amount, just remember if you post the value can be retrieved using POST global, if you get then value will be in GET global.

Comment: That works great, thank you. One question though. If they type the code wrong, the web site I'm sticking in the iframe just defaults to anrsvp.com (which appears in the iframe). Is there anyway I can get an auto-redirect and a "wrong password" pop up if they get the address wrong?

ie IF anrsvp.com loads THEN load rsvp.php AND popup "Wrong pass, try again". I realise it's not the usual method because I'm not using a database of passwords so I have nothing to correctly parse any password data against (if that makes any sense whatsoever?) :)

Comment: probably simplest method (wont be foolproof but will catch majority of incorrect entries) would be to do a pattern match on three alpha, three numeric. if match fails present pass fail message. Alternative would be to do a curl retrieve and scan result to see if its correct and if not present fail, but that would be more resource heavy.

Comment: Hey that's a good call, sadly the combinations are sometimes 1 digit, others 2/3. 

What about this... would there be a way that I could input the 90 different combinations somewhere (not accessible to the outside) to use as a check before passing onto the next page?

It doesn't really need to be *too* secure. It's just to stop nosey family/friends from seeing who else is invited, or messing with other people's invitations!! I just want it to be foolproof more than anything. 

Thanks for all your help avon guy!!

Comment: yep, put the 90 combos into an array then do a simple array match.

Comment: Awesome. Last question... In order to do this do I make a new php file, say 'array.php', then somehow in the form, do an array validation? Please could you give me some idea of how I might achieve that? 

The form is currently this: 

<form action="invitation.php" method="post"> 
<p><input name="rsvp" type="text" required="required" class="form-control required" placeholder="Enter your 6 digit code"></p> 
<button type="submit" value="" class="btn btn-1c"><span class="fa fa-paper-plane"> &nbsp;</span>send</button> 
</form>

Comment: at top of the php, in the part before you print any php, you need $possibles = array('rva858', 'someothercode'); $match = $_POST['rsvp']; if (array_search($match, $possibles) != false) { //match code in here } else { // fail code in here }

Comment: Ah okay so I don't need a separate php page, I get that, thanks! I'm a bit unsure about the {//match code in here} and {//fail code in here}. How does this all link to the form I have? What do I put into those brackets ?(Sorry for being dense...and thanks v.much again!)